# Error encountered when executing SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, etl

I am encountering the following error when executing an SSIS package:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4555B0A5-E8D7-49BD-B299-3140C34D3769} failed due to the following error: e06d7363 
Exception from HRESULT: 0xE06D7363.;
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package..ctor()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.Load(IDTSEvents events)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.LoadPackage(IDTSEvents events)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ISServerExecutionEvents.LoadPackage(PackageItem item)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ProjectOperator.StartPackage()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ProjectOperator.PerformOperation()
```

This is what I have done:

- Built the package in Visual Studio
- Import the package into the Integrated Services Catalog in SQL Server Management Studio
- Deployed the package to the Integrated Services Catalog
- Executed the package (and got the error).

I checked online, and found that 0xE06D7363 means that a C++ exception has been thrown, which doesn't really help.

I also found that 4555B0A5-E8D7-49BD-B299-3140C34D3769 refers to a object named SSIS.Package.3 in the registry, but that also doesn't help.

Has anyone encountered this, and more importantly, does anyone know of a way of resolving it?

Comment: i encountered the same error when i was building packages using visual studio (reference for sql 2008) and running it on an sql server with different version... The CLSID may differ from version to other

Comment: Thanks, @H.Fadlallah. This sounds like my issue - I am opening the SSIS project in VS 2015, and deploying to SQL Server 2014. How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: it was an old issue.. but i remeber that changing the class name of the object in you solution to the right one. i.e `Package.3` may be `Package` or something else

Comment: i remebered the issue!!! it is all about ManagedDTS.dll checkout the version used in your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If Creating ssis package from an .net application**

The problem is that that the application had been compiled with a reference to an SQL version `ManagedDTS.dll` and was being deployed to a SQL 2014 environment. Check the references and confirm that your reference to the `ManagedDTS.DLL` is using the version of the DLL that matches your production environment.

**If you are creating an Integration Services Packages using Visual Studio:**

In the `property` pages for an Integration Services project, on the `General tab` of `Configuration Properties`, select the `TargetServerVersion` property and choose `SQL Server 2016`, `SQL Server 2014`, or `SQL Server 2012`.

Read this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577.aspx) for more informations

This [Article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4253/backwards-compatibility-in-sql-server-data-tools-for-integration-services/) contains more details

Comment: How did you change the class name @H.Fadlallah? What menu or menu items in Visual Studio do you need to click to go to the dialog box that you would make the change in? Or did you make the change in another application?

Comment: Unfortunately, the project that I have open in Visual Studio is an SSIS project, and this doesn't have any references of any sort listed in Solution Explorer. Any other ideas?

Comment: i thinked that you have built your package in a application. edited my answer

Comment: H.Fadlallah - If you want to get the attention of someone other than the author of the post you're commenting (in this case that's you), you need to use the @ tagging, like this:@TolaOdejayi